# How to maintain atomicity with ConcurrentHashMap get and put methods?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

In a multi-threaded environment, I am performing get and put operations on a ConcurrentHashMap implementation. However, the results are un-expected. Please find below code and output.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Test {

    private static final List<String> bars = Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10");
    private static final String KEY = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    private static ExecutorService executorService = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
            Map<String, AtomicInteger> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
            performMapOps(map);
            executorService.shutdown();
            try {
                while (!executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
                System.out.println(map.get(KEY));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void performMapOps(Map<String, AtomicInteger> map) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= bars.size(); i++) {
            executorService.execute(() -> ops(map));
        }
    }

    private static void ops(Map<String, AtomicInteger> map) {
       if (!map.containsKey(KEY)) {
            AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(1);
            map.put(KEY, atomicInteger);
        } else {
            map.get(KEY).set(map.get(KEY).intValue() + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT - It should be 10 always, However it is not true for the above code. Please find below output.

```
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
9
10
10
```

Sometimes, it gives me value other than 10.
Please help to understand, why this un-expected behaviour and how to fix this?

Comment: You need replace body of ops with all in one operation such as `map.computeIfAbsent(KEY, k -> new AtomicInteger()). incrementAndGet()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code has a race condition. Two threads can decide at same time that `!map.containsKey(KEY)` is false and assign different `new AtomicInteger(1)` to the map.

Two threads can decide at same time that `!map.containsKey(KEY)` is true and they both could evaluate `map.get(KEY)` as the same value, so store same new value with `.set(map.get(KEY).intValue() + 1)`.

An atomic operation for update can be achieved by use of `Map.computeIfAbsent()` with `AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet()` to ensure consistent counter incrementing without the value being updated by another thread:

```
private static void ops(Map<String, AtomicInteger> map) { 
    map.computeIfAbsent(KEY, k -> new AtomicInteger()).incrementAndGet();
}
```

Comment: The original code did not have “a race condition” but multiple race conditions. Nitpicking: in the second section, the scenario of `map.get(KEY)` returning the same value is not the problem, as that’s actually the intended thing (the value returned by `map.get(KEY)` is the `AtomicInteger`). Letting aside that this is not guaranteed due to the problem described in the first section, the actual second problem is that `intValue()` may return the same value. It’s even possible that multiple updates happen while a thread is executing `intValue() + 1` and eventually reverting all of them.